# Google Play Games C++ SDK

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, google-play-services, leaderboard, cocos2d-x-3.0

I know how to use the following concept to integrate AdMob into my Cocos2d-x project.

```
JniMethodInfo t;

if (JniHelper::getStaticMethodInfo(t, "AJavaClass", "SomeFunction", "()V")) 
{
  t.env->CallStaticVoidMethod(t.classID, t.methodID);
  t.env->DeleteLocalRef(t.classID);
}
```

How do I make a corresponding method call for the following method?

```
startActivityForResult(Games.Leaderboards.getLeaderboardIntent(getApiClient(), LEADERBOARD_ID), REQUEST_LEADERBOARD);
```